# How to store error exception in a variable and return as json

Tags: api, exception, laravel-4, error-handling, php-5.6

Im working with an API used by Android Development.
My Framework: `Laravel 4.2` and PHP: `PHP5.6`

I already found a library but couldn't make it work: https://github.com/Radweb/JSON-Exception-Formatter

My problem, I have this error exception (attached images)
[image]

I can't see it properly in Mobile, it just crashes. Im using https://www.getpostman.com/ for testing my API.

What I wanted to do is return this error exception as json so that the android can catch it.

`{
 "status" : "fail",
 "messsage" : "syntax error, unexpected 's'(T_STRING), expecting ']'",
 "file" : "/app/controller/v1/UserController.php",
 "line" : "31"
}`

Comment: Do you want help with getting the JSON-Exception-Formatter library to work properly, or do you want help with configuring laravel to output JSON instead of default exception handler? It's a bit unclear in you question.

Comment: @henrik anything. the goal is store the error exception in a variable and return as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Laravel 4 output exceptions as JSON, one could simply edit the global.php as described in this article: http://fideloper.com/error-handling-with-content-negotiation

So in your app/start/global.php do something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

App::error(function(HttpExceptionInterface $exception, $code)
{

    if ( Request::header('accept') === 'application/json' )
    {
        return Response::json([
            'error' => true,
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'code' => $code],
            $code
        );
    }

});
```

Comment: No it isn't using any packages besides laravel framework

Comment: Thats amazing. No library used? okay ill try this